# Jquery ui tabs, second added tab not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If you click on title 'Link', you can see tabs not working. What did i do wrong?
And how could i make, height of each tab in addiction of content amount

Jquery:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true

  });
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

Full code [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kani339/yhxz0xe4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `id`s duplicated whereas it has to be **`unique`**. So either change `id` of 2nd `tabs` to `tabs1` and initialize as below:

```
$("#tabs,#tabs1").tabs()
```

**[DEMO with different ids](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yhxz0xe4/4/)**

or

change `id` to `class` as for both the `tabs` as below:

```
<div class="tabs">
  ....
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  ....
</div>
```

and initialize it as below:

```
$('.tabs').tabs()
```

**[DEMO with same class](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yhxz0xe4/3/)**

---

**UPDATE**

To make, height of each tab in addiction of content amount you could just add one `CSS` to `.tabs`, and set its `height` property to `auto !important`as below:

```
.tabs{
    height:auto !important;
}
```

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yhxz0xe4/5/)**

Comment: Thank You! Forgot about that ID must be Unique

Comment: and one more question. How could i make, height of each tab in addiction of content amount

Comment: Great, Thank You so much!